# Azure App Service (Windows) Config Variable

Tags: node.js, windows, azure, dotenv

I'm having an issue reading env variables on Azure App Service Windows instance. I use dotenv nodejs package for storing my env variables in .env file. It works perfectly fine on my local machine (Windows 10), but the same does not when hosted on a Windows App service. I tried some troubleshooting by printing out the env variables at run time and I get blank output for the same. Somehow it's not able to read the variables in the .env file.

I also made sure that the .env file and the entries are intact on the deployed host by logging onto the console.

Comment: App Service injects process.env.PORT into your application, so the code uses the variable to know which port to listen.

Answer (score 0):

App Service injects process.env.PORT into your application, so the code uses the variable to know which port to listen.
Open index.js and find the following line:
const port = process.env.PORT || 1337;

If you haven't done this already, 
In App Service, you can set app settings outside of your app code. Then you can access them using the standard Node.js pattern. For example, to access an app setting called NODE_ENV, use the following code:
process.env.NODE_ENV

To fetch more details, Navigate to the Debug Console site https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
Go into your site/wwwroot directory

recycleSignalEnabled - The default value is false. If enabled, your node application can connect to a named pipe (environment variable IISNODE_CONTROL_PIPE) and send a “recycle” message. This causes the w3wp to recycle gracefully.

Comment: What you've mentioned in just a description of my problem in different words. The env variables are not loaded at runtime within the App service. I'd like to know how to load them from the .env file to the respective variables in the code.